# Child DIV tag width based on the parent div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to align the child div tag   but as per below image i specified width:auto , but all 3 div are aligned left.

[fiddle link](http:////jsfiddle.net/psarun85/pfL28bve/)

is there any way i can make the child div expand automatically to make to fit the free space of parent div?

i came across several questions but not related to this, apologizes if its a duplicate.

Edit:
i want all the 3 divs to occupy 100% of the width. instead of aligning it to left. i cannot assign 33% to each because sometimes one of the child div may have more text.

here i have the image of how i expect...

[some more clarification about what i expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb1n2.png)

Comment: This is not clear.  Do you want all 3 divs together to span the entire containing div (i.e. like 3 columns 33% each)?

Comment: updated the question .. hope this is clear this time.

Comment: Draw a picture of what you WANT and explain the rules you want to use in sizing the boxes.

Comment: updated the picture of what i expect.. and thanks to Vinc for providing the solution.. not able to +1 as i dont have reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

you can set width of child element with calc function. 
62px = 20px of left and right padding, 40px of right and left margin and 2px of left and right border

```
width:calc((100% / 3) - 62px);
```

Comment: thanks but i dont want any constant width to the div tag. if it has more data it should expand by itself.  sometimes one div occupies 50% of the space and rest are 25% each. will it work during that case?

Answer (score 0):

With the effect you are trying to accomplish. You don't want to float the divs. They just need to have the correct CSS.

CSS

```
#parent {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    width: 100%;  
}
.child {
    border:1px solid #0000ff;
    background: #CCC;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    margin:20px 20px;
 }
```

[jsfiddle for vertical alignment](http://jsfiddle.net/pfL28bve/4/)

**EDIT BELOW**

If you want them all in a horizontal line, you need to remove the whitespace from the html elements and then assign the correct width and margins.

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
        test data 1
    </div><!-- remove whitespace
     --><div class="child">
        test data 2
    </div><!-- remove whitespace
     --><div class="child">
        test data 3
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#parent {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid #0000ff;
  background: #CCC;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0px 5%;
}
```

[Working Fiddle for horizontal alignment](http://jsfiddle.net/pfL28bve/7/)

Comment: Although it's hard to tell, I don't think that's what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @JimGarrison I gave a horizontal alignment option as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table-cell or flex to achieve what u want (geting all the width from your parent). If not, then another way is to play with your childs width-percentage and maybe some display-inline.. also floating will mess that up, so remove it..
as i understand u ask smth like the above snippet:

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  width:100%;
  min-height:150px;
  display: table;
}
.child {
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #0000ff;  
  padding:20px;
  background: #CCC;
  margin:10px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;

}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
        <div class="child">
            test data 1
        </div>
         <div class="child">
            test data 2
        </div>
         <div class="child">
            test data 3
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :) this is what i am expecting...  table , table cell did the magic... much appreciated your response

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to use table. You can use 3 `<td>` tag (table data) inside a `<tr>` tag